# GCP - Python create IoT device PermissionDenied

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iot

I am trying to create IoT devices on the Google Cloud through a Python script.
I have set up the project, IoT registry and authenticated my GCloud and linked the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the json from the corresponding service account.
Why I use the command line to create an account, e.g.
`gcloud iot devices create dev01 --project=... --region=... --registry=...` ,
it works.
However, my Python script (run through command prompt) does not seem to yield the same results. I used https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/samples/device-manager-samples#iot-core-create-rs256-python for the iot_v1 reference.

```
    # Generate Key
    key = rsa.generate_private_key(backend=default_backend(), public_exponent=65537, key_size=2048)
    # Get Public
    public_key = key.public_key().public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.OpenSSH, serialization.PublicFormat.OpenSSH)
    # Get Private
    pem = key.private_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
                            format=serialization.PrivateFormat.TraditionalOpenSSL,
                            encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption())
    # Decode to UTF-8
    private_key_str = pem.decode('utf-8')
    public_key_str = public_key.decode('utf-8')
    # Write keys
    with open('Key Pairs/'+deviceName+'_private.pem', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(pem)
    with open('Key Pairs/' + deviceName + '_public.pem', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(public_key)

    # Create Device
    client = iot_v1.DeviceManagerClient()
    parent = client.registry_path(PROJECTID, REGION, REGISTRY)
    deviceTemplate = {
        'id': deviceName,
        "credentials": [
            {
                "public_key": {
                    "format": iot_v1.PublicKeyFormat.RSA_X509_PEM,
                    "key": public_key_str,
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    client.create_device(request={'parent': parent, 'device': deviceTemplate})
```

The error traceback is

```
File "commissioning.py", line 46, in <module>
    client.create_device(request={'parent': parent, 'device': deviceTemplate})
  File "C:\Users\Niels\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\iot_v1\services\device_manager\client.py", line 728, in create_device
    response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
  File "C:\Users\Niels\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 145, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Niels\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 The caller does not have permission
```

I guess it is either a problem the way I use iot_v1 or with the permissions of Python. Any help/tips would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the service account being used to create the client has at least the `roles/cloudiot.provisioner` Role assigned (if you keep getting the permission errors try adding the `roles/cloudiot.admin` role to the service account, as it should grant full control of all IoT devices, find more information about all the available permissions [here](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/iam).)

Once you are sure that the service account has the correct permissions you can take advantage of the the `credentials` parameter offered by the [iot_v1.DeviceManagerClient() class](https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudiot/latest/iot_v1/services.html#google.cloud.iot_v1.services.device_manager.DeviceManagerClient) to make sure you point to the service account key file as explained on the [Authentication](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#service-account-private-key-files) section of the docs.